# SQL split string (all possible combination)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I would like to transform this string:
A1+A2+A3.B1+B2.C1
into
A1.B1.C1
A1.B2.C1
A2.B1.C1
A2.B2.C1
A3.B1.C1
A3.B2.C1

How can I do that? (note that each dimension(= a group separate by .), could have x values, I mean it can be A1+A2.B1.C1 or A1+A2.B1+B2+B3+B4+B5.C1+C2)

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.   Most databases have some sort of split functionality.

Comment: I'd look in to STRING_SPLIT() and CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only 3 columns, then just use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): number your groups from first split and then do a join 3 times and select each group on corresponding join.

```
with a as  (
 select s2.value as v, dense_rank() over(order by s1.value) as rn
  from STRING_SPLIT('A1+A2+A3.B1+B2.C1', '.') as s1
        cross apply STRING_SPLIT(s1.value, '+') as s2
)
select
  a1.v + '.' + a2.v + '.' + a3.v as val
from a as a1
  cross join a as a2
  cross join a as a3
where a1.rn = 1
  and a2.rn = 2
  and a3.rn = 3
```

```
|   val  |
----------
|A1.B1.C1|
|A2.B1.C1|
|A3.B1.C1|
|A1.B2.C1|
|A2.B2.C1|
|A3.B2.C1|
```

If you have indefinite number of groups, then it's better to use [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of dynamic SQL. What you should do:

1. Start with all the values from the first group.
2. On recursion step crossjoin all the values of the next group (i.e. step group number is current group number + 1).
3. Select the last recursion step where you'll have the result.

Code is below:

```
with a as  (
 select s2.value as v, dense_rank() over(order by s1.value) as rn
  from STRING_SPLIT('A1+A2+A3.B1+B2+B3+B4.C1+C2.D1+D2+D3', '.') as s1
        cross apply STRING_SPLIT(s1.value, '+') as s2
)
, b (val, lvl) as (
  /*Recursion base*/
  select cast(v as nvarchar(1000)) as val, rn as lvl
  from a
  where rn = 1

  union all
  /*Increase concatenation on each iteration*/
  select cast(concat(b.val, '.', a.v) as nvarchar(1000)) as val, b.lvl + 1 as lvl
  from b
    join a
      on b.lvl + 1 = a.rn /*Recursion step*/
)
select *
from b
where lvl = (select max(rn) from a) /*You need the last step*/
order by val
```

I won't add a tabular result since it is quite big. But [try it by yourself](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65a63f4f7ed4d8ecc93d7fc00599c7ee&hide=1).

Comment: Here my code with your help. I didn't mention, but I can also have more or less than 3 parts, so I'm using a dynamic SQL for this:

Comment: @user11051593 I've updated my answer for non-arbitrary number of groups without any dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL server version and [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=242c0985531d46073ffed404dca1a29a&hide=1):

```sql
with lst(s) as (select * from STRING_SPLIT('A1+A2.B1+B2+B3+B4+B5.C1+C2','.'))
select t1+'.'+t2+'.'+t3 as res from
(select * from STRING_SPLIT((select s from lst where s like 'A%'), '+')) s1(t1) cross join
(select * from STRING_SPLIT((select s from lst where s like 'B%'), '+')) s2(t2) cross join
(select * from STRING_SPLIT((select s from lst where s like 'C%'), '+')) s3(t3);
```

Of course you can grow it in a regular fashion if the number of dimensions grows.

Here is a Postgresql solution:

```sql
with x(s) as (select string_to_array('A1+A2.B1+B2+B3+B4+B5.C1+C2','.'))
select t1||'.'||t2||'.'||t3 as res from 
unnest((select string_to_array(s[1],'+') from x)) t1 cross join 
unnest((select string_to_array(s[2],'+') from x)) t2 cross join 
unnest((select string_to_array(s[3],'+') from x)) t3;
```

result:

```
res     |
--------|
A1.B1.C1|
A1.B2.C1|
A1.B3.C1|
A1.B4.C1|
A1.B5.C1|
A2.B1.C1|
A2.B2.C1|
A2.B3.C1|
A2.B4.C1|
A2.B5.C1|
A1.B1.C2|
A1.B2.C2|
A1.B3.C2|
A1.B4.C2|
A1.B5.C2|
A2.B1.C2|
A2.B2.C2|
A2.B3.C2|
A2.B4.C2|
A2.B5.C2|
```

Comment: Thans a lot, thats perfect !!

Answer (score 0):

Here my code with your help. I didn't mention, but I can also have more or less than 3 parts, so I'm using a dynamic SQL for this:

```
declare @FILTER varchar(max)='B+C+D.A+G.T+Y+R.E' 
-- Works also with A.B.C
-- Works also with A+B+C.D.E+F
-- Works also with A+B+C.D+E+F+G+H
declare @NB int
declare @SQL varchar(max)=''

select @NB=count(*) from STRING_SPLIT(@FILTER,'.')


set @SQL='
;with T(A,B) as
    (select *, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) 
     from STRING_SPLIT(''' + @FILTER + ''',''.'')
     )
     select '

;with T(V,N) as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
    from STRING_SPLIT(@FILTER,'.')
)
select @SQL=@SQL + 'T' + cast(N as varchar(max)) + ' + ''.'' + ' from T
set @SQL=left(@SQL,len(@SQL)-1) + ' as res from'

;with T(V,N) as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
    from STRING_SPLIT(@FILTER,'.')
)
select @SQL=@SQL + '
(select * from STRING_SPLIT((select A from T where B=' + cast(N as varchar(max)) + '),     ''+'')) s' + cast(N as varchar(max)) + '(t' + cast(N as varchar(max)) + ') cross join'
from T

set @SQL=left(@SQL,len(@SQL)-len('cross join'))
exec(@SQL)
```